# How can i hide and show drop down list on input click in angular7?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an `angular7` app in which i have a `dropdown` in which when i select any item from dropdown so `dropdown` closed. But i also close and open dropdown on `input` click like toggle. Like if i click on input then `dropdown` should open and when i again click on `input` so `dropdown` should close. Here i create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-me74sn)  you can see here live example of what i have

I have my `component.html` like this

```js
records = [];
  selectedName : string = '';
  nameDisplayModel = '';
  users = [
    {name : 'Fahad', value :'fahad'},
    {name : 'Saad', value :'saad'},
    {name : 'Anus', value :'anus'},
    {name : 'Hazik', value :'hazik'},
    {name : 'Ahsan', value :'ahsan'},
    {name : 'Sohaib', value :'sohaib'}
  ]

  
  credentialsSearchFilter(event: any) {
    const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    this.records = this.users.filter(function(d) {
      return d.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val;
    });
  }
  hideList(){
    this.records = [];
  }
  getNameValue(row){
      console.log('hello')
      this.nameDisplayModel = row.name;
      this.users.forEach(item=>{
        if(item.name === row.name){
          this.selectedName = row.value;
        }
      })
      this.records = [];
      console.log(this.selectedName)
  }
```

```css
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.custom-list{
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
}
.suggestion-list{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  background-color:white;
}

li {
  padding: 0.5em;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.wrapper{
  padding: 20px;
}
li:hover{
  background-color:#a560f3;
  cursor : pointer;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="row mt-3">
  <div class="col-6">
      
   <div class="autocomplete">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="text here" (keyup)="credentialsSearchFilter($event)" (blur)="hideList()" [(ngModel)]="nameDisplayModel">
    <ul *ngIf="records.length > 0" class="suggestion-list mt-2">
     <li *ngFor="let record of records" (mousedown)="getNameValue(record)">{{record.name}}</li>
    </ul>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example of [StackBlitz Link is](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wyhrse?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), and ...

add click toggle () event in your input  like this...

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="text here" (keyup)="credentialsSearchFilter($event)" (blur)="hideList()" [(ngModel)]="nameDisplayModel" (click)="toggle($event)">
```

Then, in your toggle() is...

```
toggle(event: any){
  this.toggleBool === false ? this.toggleBool=true: this.toggleBool=false;
  this.toggleBool ? this.credentialsSearchFilter(event) :this.hideList() ;
}
```

and default toggleBool is set to false as property...

```
  toggleBool =false;
```